# I would like be able to sleep() in Anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic

I have a function that contains some commands which I'd like to execute after a certain amount of time (with something like `Thread.sleep`), but I can't seem to find the one line code that will do the job.

I've tried `Thread.sleep(1)` and `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1)`, but I feel there should be some built-in method to do the same thing.

> Note: I'm not working with agents here so the delay/wait blocks don't
> apply.

Comment: use the event object

Comment: I'm not sure I get the context of your question.. what is built-in method for you? Thread.sleep is also a *built-in* in Java, right? why don't you like it?

Comment: +1 for the question wording :D . But agree with Felipe: use an event or a Dynamic Event. Check the help and example models to learn how they work. "sleep()" sends your thread to sleep, something different than passing the model time

Comment: I do have a solution that uses the event block (basically I have the event execute every second and check a variable to decide whether to execute the function or not, but what I really need is something like
do{
 //actions here
 //wait one second before looping again 
} while (condition)
 and it's not a function that needs to be called all the time? so that's why I rather not use an event

@Giorgi I'm making something in Anylogic and if I try using the aforementioned methods I get "Description: Unhandled exception type InterruptedException"

Comment: Again just to clarify, I'm calling a certain function that contains a loop, and I'd just like it to wait a second before going through the loop again and was just wondering if there is an alternative to having an event that executes every second and checks if it needs to execute the loop.  More specifically, I have a function that when called, removes an agent, but I'd like to only remove the agent if it is in a certain state, so I'd like the function to iterate through population, and if no agents are in that state to wait a second before trying again.